# Pattern, matcher in Java, REGEX help

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to just get rid of duplicate consecutive words from a text file, and someone mentioned that I could do something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) \\1");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
int i = 0;
for (String s : lineOfWords) { // line of words is a List<String> that has each line read in from txt file
Matcher m = p.matcher(s.toUpperCase());
// and then do something like
while (m.find()) {
  // do something here
}
```

I tried looking at the m.end to see if I could create a new string, or remove the item(s) where the matches are, but I wasn't sure how it works after reading the documentation.  For example, as a test case to see how it worked, I did:

```
if (m.find()) {
System.out.println(s.substring(i, m.end()));
    }
```

To the text file that has: `This is an example example test test test.`

Why is my output `This is`?

Edit:

if I have an AraryList lineOfWords that reads each line from a line of .txt file and then I create a new ArrayList to hold the modified string.  For example

```
List<String> newString = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : lineOfWords { 
   s = s.replaceAll( code from Kobi here);
   newString.add(s);
}
```

but then it doesn't give me the new s, but the original s.  Is it because of shallow vs deep copy?

Comment: What's `i` in that second fragment?  There is no trace of it anywhere else in the code you show...

Comment: sorry, i is equal to 0, added it back in.

Comment: Hi, Crystal. It is best to ask a new question in that case, it really is another question on another subject. (on a relevant note - back when I studied Java it didn't have generics nor foreach loops `:P`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\w+)\\b(\\s+\\1)+\\b", "$1");
```

That regex is a bit stronger than yours - it checks for whole words (no partial matches), and gets rid of any number of consecutive repetitions.
The regex captures a first word: `\b(\w+)\b`, and then attempts to match spaces and repetitions of that word: `(\s+\1)+`. The final `\b` is to avoid partial matching of `\1`, as in `"for formatting"`.

Comment: That helped out a lot.  Is there a way to check for things that are different case?  Like "test Test"?

Comment: @Crystal - Thanks! You can add `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex to make it case-insensitive, it seems like the standard solution for `replaceAll`.

Comment: Another question Kobi if you have a second, if I am looping through an Arraylist that has my lines of words from a test file, and if I did a foreach loop to go through it, like for (String s: lineOfWords) { s = s.replaceAll..., then how would I add this new "s" to my new ArrayList to return.  I think it has to do with shallow vs deep copy, but not sure.  I tried pseudo-coding in my initial question above.  Thx!

Comment: You mustn’t use `\b` and such in Java. They are [super-broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261).  For example, the string `élève` is not matched by the pattern `\b\w+\b` *anywhere whatsoever*.

Comment: @tchrist - Hello! Yes, I've noticed you raise that unfortunate issue lately. I'll keep it in mind when Unicode support is necessary. I guess the best workaround here is not to use a monstrosity of a regex for every `\b` or `\w`, but to use a regex library that works `:P`

Answer (score 1):

The first match is "Th**IS IS** an example...", so `m.end()` points to the end of the second "is". I'm not sure why you use `i` for the start index; try `m.start()` instead.

To improve your regex, use `\b` before and after the word to indicate that there should be word boundaries: `(\\b\\w+\\b)`. Otherwise, as you're seeing, you'll get matches inside of words.